# Adding a delete icon to each <option> element of a <select>

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `<select>` element in the jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/ekuSd/ - where I'd like to add a red x icon at the right of each option to give the user the ability to delete that option. I've tried sticking the img tag in the area between the tags but that doesn't work. Does anyone see a way to do  this?

Thanks.

```
<select id="filename">
    <option value="File" selected="">[File name]</option>
    <option value="file1.html">file1</option>
    <option value="file2.html">file2</option>
    <option value="file3.html">file3</option>
    <option value="file4.html">file4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you'll have to use a plugin for this..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this cross-browser with an image and not with a Unicode glyph like @Tucker proposed, you'll have to use a JavaScript widget.

I'd personally recommend [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/)'s [Selectable](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly. Then, you have two options:

1. You can fake your own select, so that you can add html elements in your options. You will need to write lots of javascript and css lines, or use a plugin, like @hungerpain said.
2. You can have an external x icon:

```html
<select id="filename">
    <option value="File" selected class="placeholder">[File name]</option>
    <option value="file1.html">file1</option>
    <option value="file2.html">file2</option>
    <option value="file3.html">file3</option>
    <option value="file4.html">file4</option>
</select>
<span id="delete">✖</span>
```

```css
option.placeholder{
    display:none;
}
#delete{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```js
var del = document.getElementById('delete'),
    sel = document.getElementById('filename');
del.onclick = function(){
    var opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
    if(opt.className !== 'placeholder'){
        sel.removeChild(opt);
    }
};
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/7AhSN/

Answer (score 1):

Nothing suggested here looks attractive to me. I thought there might be an easy way that I was overlooking, but clearly that's not the case.  I think instead I'll let the person select a particular file from the drop down list and then when the file is displayed, provide a way there to delete it.  That's probably better anyway because you can see exactly what it is you're deleting, instead of just deleting a file name.